# Shared resource and async Web API call

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, castle-windsor

I have a simple Web API method that looks like this:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RunTask(TaskType taskType)
{
    var taskId = await TaskManager.CreateTask(taskType);
    TaskManager.Run(taskId);

    return new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content =
            new StringContent($"Task {taskType.GetDescription()} was started.")
    };
}
```

`TaskManager.Run` is decalared like this:

```
public async Task Run(int id)
```

I was expecting it to return "Task was started" message immediately after `TaskManager.Run(taskId)` But the request continues to run synchronously.

But if to replace the call `TaskManager.Run(taskId)` with:

```
 Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100)));
```

Then it runs asynchronously.

So I believe this is something to do with the resources shared by `TaskManager` and main thread. Can a shared resource lock the execution?

I'm using Castle Windsor. One `WindsorContainer` container is declared in Web API project. 
TaskManager utilizes BaseTaskRunner class inside of it. One more `WindsorContainer` is declared in `BaseTaskRunner`. 
Web API's container uses `LifeStyle.PerWebRequest` for all components. `BaseTaskRunner`'s container uses `LifeStyle.Singleton` (not sure if it's correct LifeStyle). Could the call be locked for example by DdContext or other classes declared in both of the containers?

**UPD:**
I don't want to wait the TaskManager.Run to complete. But what happens is that return statement still waits for the TaskManager.Run to complete (even without await statement on TaskManager.Run). 
In other words it does not matter how I call the TaskManager.Run:

```
TaskManager.Run(taskId);
```

or

```
await TaskManager.Run(taskId);
```

It waits for TaskManager.Run to complete in both cases.

Here is the code of TaskManager:

```
 public class TaskManager : ITaskManager
    {
        public IRepository<BackgroundTask> TaskRepository { get; set; }
        public async Task<int> CreateTask(TaskType type, byte[] data = null, object config = null)
        {
            var task = new BackgroundTask
            {
                Type = type,
                Status = BackgroundTaskStatus.New,
                Config = config?.SerializeToXml(),
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                Data = data
            };

            TaskRepository.Add(task);
            TaskRepository.SaveChanges();

            return task.Id;
        }

        public async Task Run(int id, bool removeOnComplete = true)
        {
            var task = TaskRepository.GetById(id);
            Run(task, removeOnComplete);
        }

        public async Task Run(TaskType type, bool removeOnComplete = true)
        {
            var tasksToRun = TaskRepository.Get(t => t.Type == type);
            tasksToRun.ForEachAsync(t => Run(t, removeOnComplete));
        }

        public async Task Run(BackgroundTask task, bool removeOnComplete = true)
        {
            switch (task.Type)
            {
                case TaskType.SpreadsheetImport:
                    new SpreadsheetImportTaskRunner().Run(task);
                    break;                    
            }                  
        }
}
```

And some other classes:

```
public class SpreadsheetImportTaskRunner : BaseTaskRunner
    {
        public IForecastSpreadsheetManager SpreadsheetManager { get; set; }
        protected override void Execute()
        {
            SpreadsheetManager.ImportActuals(Task.Data);
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
            SpreadsheetManager = _container.Resolve<IForecastSpreadsheetManager>();
        }
    }
```

BaseTaskRunner:

```
public class BaseTaskRunner
    {
        public IRepository<BackgroundTask> TaskRepository { get; set; }

        protected IWindsorContainer _container = new WindsorContainer();
        protected BackgroundTask Task { get; set; }

        public async Task Run(BackgroundTask task)
        {
            Initialize();
            Task = task;

            try
            {               
                Execute();               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SetError(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        protected virtual void Execute()
        {

        }

        protected virtual void Initialize()
        {
            _container.Install(new TaskRunnerComponentsInstaller());
            TaskRepository = _container.Resolve<IRepository<BackgroundTask>>();
        }   
    }
```

I still believe this is something to do with the WindsorContainer and common classes which are resolved in several different threads.

Comment: That's confusing  - why do you need to await  `TaskManager.CreateTask(taskType)` and not `TaskManager.Run(taskId);`? Which operation exactly are you trying to await?

Comment: I need to await TaskManager.CreateTask(taskType) because it retunrs taskId. Then I'm passing the taskId to Run method and want it to run in background while "Task was started" message will be returned to the user.

Comment: But why does getting taskId need to async? Do you fully understand the async / await pattern (or async programming in general)?

Comment: Well, fix me if I'm wrong. TaskId is an Id of newly created task and I need to wait the CreateTask to complete because without that the Run method cannot be called. So 'await' waits for CreateTask to complete. After that I want to run the 'Run' method in background (it's a long runnig task) while client will get the response. Something is wrong with my code?

Comment: If all you need is to execute a Task in the background, have you considered using the simple `Task.Run()` api?

Comment: Are you getting any warnings on your code? If not, could you show us how does `Run()` look like?

Comment: @shay__ You're right, that's exactly what I want. I don't want to wait the TaskManager.Run to complete. But what happens is that return statement still waits for the TaskManager.Run to complete (even without await statement on TaskManager.Run).

Comment: Did I not answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're not using `await` on the `Task` being returned from the invocation of the `TaskManager.Run` function. Consider the below:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RunTask(TaskType taskType)
{
    var taskId = await TaskManager.CreateTask(taskType);
    await TaskManager.Run(taskId);

    return new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content =
            new StringContent($"Task {taskType.GetDescription()} was started.")
    };
}
```

Now it will work asynchronously as you'd expect. The `await` sets a continuation marker in the `async` state-machine, instructing it to return to this portion of the method upon completion of the asynchronous operation defined in the `TaskManager.Run`.

**UPDATE**

You are missing lots of `await` statements, and there are times where you need to not mark methods as `async`. It appears as though there are some mis-understandings as it pertains to these keywords. Here is what your `TaskManager` class should look like.

```
public class TaskManager : ITaskManager
{
    public IRepository<BackgroundTask> TaskRepository { get; set; }

    public async Task<int> CreateTask(TaskType type, 
                                      byte[] data = null, 
                                      object config = null)
    {
        var task = new BackgroundTask
        {
            Type = type,
            Status = BackgroundTaskStatus.New,
            Config = config?.SerializeToXml(),
            Created = DateTime.Now,
            Data = data
        };

        TaskRepository.Add(task);
        TaskRepository.SaveChanges();

        return task.Id;
    }

    public ask Run(int id, bool removeOnComplete = true)
    {
        var task = TaskRepository.GetById(id);
        return Run(task, removeOnComplete);
    }

    public Task Run(TaskType type, bool removeOnComplete = true)
    {
        var tasksToRun = TaskRepository.Get(t => t.Type == type);
        return tasksToRun.ForEachAsync(t => Run(t, removeOnComplete));
    }

    public Task Run(BackgroundTask task, bool removeOnComplete = true)
    {
        switch (task.Type)
        {
            case TaskType.SpreadsheetImport:
                return new SpreadsheetImportTaskRunner().Run(task);
                break;                    
            }                  
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, if the method is marked as a return type of `Task` and the method doesn't need to unwind any tasks within its execution it can simply return the `Task` functionality for its implementation. For example, notice how dramatically my `TaskManager` class differs from yours -- I'm only marking methods as `async` that need to actually `await`. These two keywords should be married, if a method uses `async` there should be an `await`. But only use `await` if the method needs to unwind and use the asynchronous operation.

Comment: Assuming `TaskManager.Run()` returns a Task, your answer is right.

Comment: That's how it is defined in the question

Comment: Yep, didn't notice it :)